# ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `silence' for)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, kaminari

I have very strange problem on heroku. I have view that looks like this:

```
= content_for :header_title do
  = t('.header_title')

- if @appointments.exists?
  %table.table.table-striped.table-bordered.table-hover
    %thead
      %tr
        %th= t('.id')
        %th= t('.athena_health_id')
        %th= t('.start_time')
        %th= t('.duration')
        %th= t('.provider')
        %th= t('.created_at')
        %th= t('.updated_at')
    %tbody
      = render @appointments

  = paginate @appointments
- else
  %h3.text-center= t('.appointments_not_found')
%hr/
```

Nothing special. When I visit page that is using this template on heroku i receive:

```
 ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `silence' for #<Logger:0x007f7a86267a70>):
```

Spec are passing. On my local everything is working fine. I don't know what is going on. Stacktrace is showing that the problem is following line:

```
= paginate @appointments
```

I'm using Rails 5.0 and kaminari (1.0.0.alpha). Any ideas?

Edit:
In my production.rb I have:

```
  if ENV['RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT'].present?
    config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Logger.new(STDOUT))
  end

config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
```

Comment: The error seems unable to find "silence" method for a class called `Logger`. Does your code have a `Logger` class or is that on Heroku's end?

Comment: No, my class does not have logger class. In production.rb I have also:

  if ENV['RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT'].present?
    config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Logger.new(STDOUT))
  end

config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

Comment: Do you have seen [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/20492) issue on github? `silence` method of `::Logger` class was deprecated since Rails4.2 and it was removed from Rails5.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Rails5 `silence` method was removed from the `::Logger` base class (see this [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/20492))

So instead to pass a `::Logger` instance, try to pass an `ActiveSupport::Logger` instance which expose the `silence` method (see [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/LoggerSilence.html#method-i-silence)), like this:

`config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT))`

note: 
`ActiveSupport::Logger` inherit from the `::Logger` base class and include `LoggerSilence` module (see [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Logger.html))

An example from my `rails` console (rails5 and ruby2.3.0)

```
logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Logger.new(STDOUT))
 => #<Logger:0x007f890b8a3d10 @progname=nil, @level=0, @default_formatter=#<Logger::Formatter:0x007f890b8a2cd0 @datetime_format=nil>, @formatter=#<ActiveSupport::Logger::SimpleFormatter:0x007f890b8a26e0 @datetime_format=nil>, @logdev=#<Logger::LogDevice:0x007f890b8a2870 @shift_size=nil, @shift_age=nil, @filename=nil, @dev=#<IO:<STDOUT>>, @mon_owner=nil, @mon_count=0, @mon_mutex=#<Thread::Mutex:0x007f890b8a2730>>> 
logger.silence
NoMethodError: undefined method `silence' for #<Logger:0x007f890b8a3d10>
# ...

logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT))
 => #<ActiveSupport::Logger:0x007f890bd2a028 @progname=nil, @level=0, @default_formatter=#<Logger::Formatter:0x007f890bd29fb0 @datetime_format=nil>, @formatter=#<ActiveSupport::Logger::SimpleFormatter:0x007f890bd29f10 @datetime_format=nil>, @logdev=#<Logger::LogDevice:0x007f890bd29f60 @shift_size=nil, @shift_age=nil, @filename=nil, @dev=#<IO:<STDOUT>>, @mon_owner=nil, @mon_count=0, @mon_mutex=#<Thread::Mutex:0x007f890bd29f38>>, @local_levels=#<Concurrent::Map:0x007f890bd29ec0 entries=0 default_proc=nil>> 
logger.silence
LocalJumpError: no block given (yield)
# The method exists, but I don't pass any block
```